# Обнаружение и выстрел в конкретный цвет на камере Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть Plane, на Plane проецирует текстуру Projector, над прожектором - камера. Задача - там, где прожектор проецирует чёрный цвет, стрелять туда рейкастом.

Это должно было бы выглядеть как то так

```
foreach(Pixelinfo pixelInfo on Camera.GetAllPixels)
{
if(pixelInfo.Color == black)
{
Physics.Raycast(transform.position, pixelInfo.coord.ScreenToWorldPoint)
}
}
```

Но в у камеры нет методов узнать содержимое всех пикселей, которые она рендерит. Как это сделать?

Comment: как определяется на сцене точка с черным цветом? Ты перемещаешь некий черный обьект?

Comment: @Andrew Нет, никакого объекта - просто проекция проектора. Это не должно быть зависимо от объекта, просто хотелось бы систему вида
`if(Черный пиксель во вью камеры ){Raycast в этот чёрный пиксель)`

Comment: Прямой такой возможности тебе никто не даст. Эта задача требует слишком много ресурсов и слишком мало кому может понадобится. Только собственная реализация - делай скрин, переводи в монохромку и проверяй кажый пиксель на соответствие  не ниже некоего уровня темноты.